# How to set/change Logstash's @version field?

Tags: logstash

How to set `@version` for Logstash's each log?

`@version` field of every log is just `"1"`, and I can't figure out how to set it to `2` or something.

I think its usage is to index several versions of logs.  Once logging format is changed (for example, I add a "useragent" filter for my logs), I can set `@version` to `2`.

Comment: Give this a read. Probably answers all your questions : https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support

Comment: @TheUknown thank you for your reply.  I read it but it is for elasticsearch, not for logstash.  I have installed logstash-output-mongodb, so logs are sent to mongodb with `@version` always=1

Comment: Logstash is just a shipper which adds data into elastic search. Version is maintained in ES index. Set an id for the document you are indexing and add it to elastic and post that update the same id again and you will see the version will get updated to 2.

Comment: When you say set logstash version where exactly do you se that?  Are you taking about version only in log file? I don’t think there’s anything such as that. Logstash just puts events as they come into ES index